# What happens to a Redis data store if the data exceeds available ram?

Tags: nosql, redis, key-value-store

What happens to a Redis data store if the data exceeds available ram?

Comment: My question isn't the duplicate, i asked it almost a year earlier

Comment: Sadly, [age doesn't matter](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252929/which-question-is-the-better-reference-for-a-duplicate) -> it is the better question with better answers that is the one the other questions is a duplicate of. The question this question is a duplicate of has answers that updates as per Redis VM being deprecated. There are updates on that question to handle that, but not on this question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think there is a store size setting in redis config that will stop you adding more data than can fit in the store you have set up. If you set up a store that doesn't fit in physical memory, it will simply ask the OS for more memory and some of it will be paged to disk, with obvious performance consequences.

The next version of redis has its own virtual memory implementation which can store less frequently used keys on disk - http://antirez.com/post/redis-virtual-memory-story.html

Comment: I assumed as such but the blog post about it supporting Vmem soon was very useful, I will be waiting until 2.0 is released before considering any usage of Redis since currently my usage applications wouldn't need a 100% coverage in memory and only the hotspots would be important. This would also greatly offer the flexibility of running Redis in a low cost VPS and scale out if I ever need to instead of having to start from the higher scale since it would require enough memory for every object in it currently.

Comment: Redis VM is actually deprecated.