# What does Redis do when it runs out of memory?

Tags: nosql, redis

This might be easy question but I am having a hard time finding the answer. How does Redis 2.0 handle running out of maximum allocated memory? How does it decide which data to remove or which data to keep in memory?

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604831/what-happens-to-a-redis-data-store-if-the-data-exceeds-available-ram

Answer (score 121, accepted):

If you have virtual memory functionality turned on (**EDIT: now deprecated**), then Redis starts to store the "not-so-frequently-used" data to disk when memory runs out.

If virtual memory in Redis is disabled (the default) and the `maxmemory` parameter is set (the default), Redis will not use any more memory than `maxmemory` allows.  If you turn `maxmemory` off, Redis will start using virtual memory (i.e. swap), and performance will drop tremendously.

Newer versions of Redis have various policies when `maxmemory` is reached:

- `volatile-lru` - remove a key among the
  ones with an expire set, trying to
  remove keys not recently used.
- `volatile-ttl` - remove a key among the
  ones with an expire set, trying to
  remove keys with short remaining time
  to live.
- `volatile-random` - remove a
  random key among the ones with an
  expire set.
- `allkeys-lru` - like
  `volatile-lru`, but will remove every
  kind of key, both normal keys or keys
  with an expire set.
- `allkeys-random` -
  like `volatile-random`, but will remove
  every kind of keys, both normal keys
  and keys with an expire set.

If you pick a policy that only removes keys with an EXPIRE set, then when Redis runs out of memory, it looks like the program just aborts the malloc() operation.  That is, if you try to store more data, the write operation simply fails.

Some links for more info:

- http://antirez.com/post/redis-as-LRU-cache.html
- http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/10/30/handling-out-of-memory-conditions-in-c/

Comment: Redis Virtual Memory is now deprecated. See http://redis.io/topics/virtual-memory

Comment: What do you do when you are using Redis as more than an evictable cache? How do you manage getting important data off of Redis and into another form of storage before it is destroyed? Can you pair that with eviction as memory fills up?

Comment: @jocull - Moving data out of Redis before it fills up is a detail left up to the application. If you do nothing, Redis will run out of memory. At that point, subsequent writes will fail. You can monitor Redis memory usage and write custom application logic to move data around.

Answer (score 22):

From [**redis.conf**](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antirez/redis/2.8/redis.conf), version 2.8

```
# Don't use more memory than the specified amount of bytes.
# When the memory limit is reached Redis will try to remove keys
# according to the eviction policy selected (see maxmemory-policy).
#
# If Redis can't remove keys according to the policy, or if the policy is
# set to 'noeviction', Redis will start to reply with errors to commands
# that would use more memory, like SET, LPUSH, and so on, and will continue
# to reply to read-only commands like GET.
#
# This option is usually useful when using Redis as an LRU cache, or to set
# a hard memory limit for an instance (using the 'noeviction' policy).
#
# WARNING: If you have slaves attached to an instance with maxmemory on,
# the size of the output buffers needed to feed the slaves are subtracted
# from the used memory count, so that network problems / resyncs will
# not trigger a loop where keys are evicted, and in turn the output
# buffer of slaves is full with DELs of keys evicted triggering the deletion
# of more keys, and so forth until the database is completely emptied.
#
# In short... if you have slaves attached it is suggested that you set a lower
# limit for maxmemory so that there is some free RAM on the system for slave
# output buffers (but this is not needed if the policy is 'noeviction').
#
# maxmemory <bytes>

# MAXMEMORY POLICY: how Redis will select what to remove when maxmemory
# is reached. You can select among five behaviors:
#
# volatile-lru -> remove the key with an expire set using an LRU algorithm
# allkeys-lru -> remove any key according to the LRU algorithm
# volatile-random -> remove a random key with an expire set
# allkeys-random -> remove a random key, any key
# volatile-ttl -> remove the key with the nearest expire time (minor TTL)
# noeviction -> don't expire at all, just return an error on write operations
#
# Note: with any of the above policies, Redis will return an error on write
#       operations, when there are no suitable keys for eviction.
#
#       At the date of writing these commands are: set setnx setex append
#       incr decr rpush lpush rpushx lpushx linsert lset rpoplpush sadd
#       sinter sinterstore sunion sunionstore sdiff sdiffstore zadd zincrby
#       zunionstore zinterstore hset hsetnx hmset hincrby incrby decrby
#       getset mset msetnx exec sort
#
# The default is:
#
# maxmemory-policy volatile-lru
```

Comment: The default `maxmemory-policy` in Redis 3.2 is now `noeviction`: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antirez/redis/3.2/redis.conf

Answer (score 8):

Update redis 4.0

```
127.0.0.1:6379> MEMORY HELP
1) "MEMORY DOCTOR                        - Outputs memory problems report"
2) "MEMORY USAGE <key> [SAMPLES <count>] - Estimate memory usage of key"
3) "MEMORY STATS                         - Show memory usage details"
4) "MEMORY PURGE                         - Ask the allocator to release memory"
5) "MEMORY MALLOC-STATS                  - Show allocator internal stats"
```

> /usr/local/etc/redis.conf

```
############################## MEMORY MANAGEMENT ################################

# Set a memory usage limit to the specified amount of bytes.
# When the memory limit is reached Redis will try to remove keys
# according to the eviction policy selected (see maxmemory-policy).
#
# If Redis can't remove keys according to the policy, or if the policy is
# set to 'noeviction', Redis will start to reply with errors to commands
# that would use more memory, like SET, LPUSH, and so on, and will continue
# to reply to read-only commands like GET.
#
# This option is usually useful when using Redis as an LRU or LFU cache, or to
# set a hard memory limit for an instance (using the 'noeviction' policy).
#
# WARNING: If you have slaves attached to an instance with maxmemory on,
# the size of the output buffers needed to feed the slaves are subtracted
# from the used memory count, so that network problems / resyncs will
# not trigger a loop where keys are evicted, and in turn the output
# buffer of slaves is full with DELs of keys evicted triggering the deletion
# of more keys, and so forth until the database is completely emptied.
#
# In short... if you have slaves attached it is suggested that you set a lower
# limit for maxmemory so that there is some free RAM on the system for slave
# output buffers (but this is not needed if the policy is 'noeviction').
#
# maxmemory <bytes>

# MAXMEMORY POLICY: how Redis will select what to remove when maxmemory
# is reached. You can select among five behaviors:
#
# volatile-lru -> Evict using approximated LRU among the keys with an expire set.
# allkeys-lru -> Evict any key using approximated LRU.
# volatile-lfu -> Evict using approximated LFU among the keys with an expire set.
# allkeys-lfu -> Evict any key using approximated LFU.
# volatile-random -> Remove a random key among the ones with an expire set.
# allkeys-random -> Remove a random key, any key.
# volatile-ttl -> Remove the key with the nearest expire time (minor TTL)
# noeviction -> Don't evict anything, just return an error on write operations.
#
# LRU means Least Recently Used
# LFU means Least Frequently Used
#
# Both LRU, LFU and volatile-ttl are implemented using approximated
# randomized algorithms.
#
# Note: with any of the above policies, Redis will return an error on write
#       operations, when there are no suitable keys for eviction.
#
#       At the date of writing these commands are: set setnx setex append
#       incr decr rpush lpush rpushx lpushx linsert lset rpoplpush sadd
#       sinter sinterstore sunion sunionstore sdiff sdiffstore zadd zincrby
#       zunionstore zinterstore hset hsetnx hmset hincrby incrby decrby
#       getset mset msetnx exec sort
#
# The default is:
#
# maxmemory-policy noeviction

# LRU, LFU and minimal TTL algorithms are not precise algorithms but approximated
# algorithms (in order to save memory), so you can tune it for speed or
# accuracy. For default Redis will check five keys and pick the one that was
# used less recently, you can change the sample size using the following
# configuration directive.
#
# The default of 5 produces good enough results. 10 Approximates very closely
# true LRU but costs more CPU. 3 is faster but not very accurate.
#
# maxmemory-samples 5
```

Answer (score 5):

I just recently started reading about Redis, so I'm not positive. But, I did come across a few tidbits that may be useful.

Here's a snippet from http://antirez.com/post/redis-as-LRU-cache.html:

> Another way to use Redis as a cache is
>   the maxmemory directive, a feature
>   that allows specifying a maximum
>   amount of memory to use. When new data
>   is added to the server, and the memory
>   limit was already reached, the server
>   will remove some old data deleting a
>   volatile key, that is, a key with an
>   EXPIRE (a timeout) set, even if the
>   key is still far from expiring
>   automatically.

Also, Redis 2.0 has a VM mode where all keys must fit in memory, but the values for the rarely used keys can be on disk:

- http://redis.io/topics/virtual-memory
- http://antirez.com/post/redis-virtual-memory-story.html

Answer (score 3):

If you wonder what Redis (2.8) actually responds when it reaches the maximum defined by its configuration, it looks like this:

```
$ redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> GET 5
"bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"
127.0.0.1:6379> SET 5 a
(error) OOM command not allowed when used memory > 'maxmemory'.
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently experienced a no-free-memory situation and my application ground to a halt (writes not possible, reads were possible), running PHP scripts stopped dead in their tracks mid-way and had to be `kill -9`'d manually (even after memory was made available).

I assumed data loss (or data inconsistency) had occurred so I did a `flushdb` and restored from backups. Lesson learned? Backups are your friend.

Answer (score -3):

Redis is not a cache like memcached, by default (where the `maxmemory-policy` parameter is set to `noeviction`) all data you put into redis will not be removed, the only exception is in using EXPIRE.

Comment: So what does it do when it runs out of of memory? It will just store new data in disk not memory?

Comment: This is (now) incorrect, Redis has a key eviction mechanism, with several available policies: http://redis.io/topics/lru-cache

Comment: @LoicAG: Sounds perfectly correct to me... unless there's an expriation policy, Redis won't evict any key. And that's good : I, for instance, cannot afford to have Redis get rid of keys on its own.

Comment: @Cory: If there's an eviction policy set up, it will remove existing keys. However, if you didn't set any eviction policy, you should receive an out of memory error.

Comment: @Michael I suppose it's a matter of terminology: there is always a maxmemory-policy in place, and the default is indeed "noeviction"; but the "allkeys-lru" and "allkeys-random" policies evict keys from the entire set, and the other ("volatile-*") evict keys from the subset of keys that have a TTL defined.