# Angular-translate using Redis for storage

Tags: angularjs, redis

I am trying to use angular-translate for my application. I want to use Redis as custom storage service. Redis automatically moves 'not-so-frequently-used' data to disk when it runs out-of-memory. Can anyone tell me how to make the files related to translation service persistent on Redis(primary storage) even if out-of-memory condition exists.

I refered this link
[What does Redis do when it runs out of memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068518/what-does-redis-do-when-it-runs-out-of-memory)

Comment: Redis VM is deprecated: https://redis.io/topics/virtual-memory