# Python redis subscribe can not get all datas?

Tags: python, redis, queue, apache-kafka

I am using python to get datas from redis and then parser it to kafka. It works well in most situations.

But when I use python to simulate build the data to redis, or there was a fast put-in datas in queuen, I can't get all the data.

Here is my code about redis producer to simulate build 20000 datas to redis:

```
rc = redis.Redis(host='127.0.0.1', port=6379)
rc.ping()
ps = rc.pubsub()
ps.subscribe('bdwaf')
r_str = "--8198b507-A--\n[22/Jun/2017:14:13:19 +0800]ucTcxcMcicAcAcAcicAcAcAm 192.168.1.189 50054 127.0.0.1 80\n"
for i in range(0, 20000):
    rc.publish('bdwaf', r_str)
```

and the redis consumer also the kafka producer is:

```
rc = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379)
rc.ping()
ps = rc.pubsub()
ps.subscribe('bdwaf')
num = 0
for item in ps.listen():
     if item['type'] == 'message':
         num += 1
         a.parser(item['data'])
         print num
```

It only prints out like 4000 datas.

If I comment the `a.parser(item['data'])`, it can print out all datas num.

Or wirte `sleep(0.001)` in the redis producer, it can print out all datas num too.

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using [redis-py](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py).

The documentation refers to `listen` as older version of the lib... Maybe you should use another method for message reading. For example with a callback

```
p = r.pubsub()

def my_handler(message):
    print 'MY HANDLER: ', message['data']
    if item['type'] == 'message':
         num += 1
         a.parser(item['data'])
         print num

p.subscribe('bdwaf', my_handler)
# read the subscribe confirmation message
p.get_message()
```

Edit:

It is possible that your redis server is running out of memory when you publish 20000 messages at once. Try increasing redis memory in `redis.conf` file

```
maxmemory 500mb # or greater if needed
```

It is a memory problem, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068518/what-does-redis-do-when-it-runs-out-of-memory/5163220#5163220) question for more information on how to handle it.

Comment: thank you ,but it still got that problems.it's funny that i simulated build the datas num lower than 17000, it always work fine,but when it higher than 17000,it can't consume all the datas.

Comment: Is it possible that your redis instance, just isn't big enough to hold all 20000 messages at once? Have you noticed any errors?

Comment: it seems it is the redis instance problem,i run redis-cli in terminal and SUBSCRIBE ,it will force exit  when i   put in more than 20000 datas once.how can I fix this??

Comment: edited answer with more info. If it isn't a memory issue, can you post redis server logs ?