# redis more faster than subscribers,can't got all datas

Tags: python, redis, queue, redis-py

I was using python to publish and subscribe message-queueing

**publisher**:

```
rc = redis.Redis(host='127.0.0.1', port=6379)
rc.ping()
ps = rc.pubsub()
ps.subscribe('bdwaf')
r_str = "--8198b507-A--"
for i in range(0, 20000):
    rc.publish('bdwaf', r_str)
```

**subscriber**:

```
rc = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379)
rc.ping()
ps = rc.pubsub()
ps.subscribe('bdwaf')
num = 0
while True:
    item = ps.get_message()
        if item:
             num += 1
             if item['type'] == 'message':
                  a.parser(item['data'])
             print num
```

when the publisher loop range is higher than 20000, the subscriber seems to not get all datas, only when i add a sleep method to the publisher, it can work.

how can I make it work without adding a sleep method to the publisher, and no matter what is the range of the publisher to publish data, the subscriber can get all datas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python redis subscribe can not get all datas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44777455/python-redis-subscribe-can-not-get-all-datas)

Answer (score 0):

You can persist the messages in a distributed task queue. commonly used with redis is a distributed task queue written in python called celery (http://www.celeryproject.org/)