# redis: delete oldest keys when memory limited

Tags: redis

I have keys I want to keep indefinitely in redis provided I have enough memory.  However, if redis runs low on memory, then I'd like it to remove the oldest keys first.  I looked at the "eviction policy" options and it appears redis doesn't support this out of the box.  https://support.redislabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/203290657-What-eviction-policies-do-you-support-

How could I implement this myself using commands available as part of the redis-client api?

Here's some pseudocode that might work to give a flavor for what I need:

```
1.  Get the first N keys from a list sorted by key date asc.
2.  Delete the oldest keys.
3.  Repeat until memory is no longer constrained.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does Redis do when it runs out of memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068518/what-does-redis-do-when-it-runs-out-of-memory)

Comment: Read the linked answer, and the docs in the config file about `maxmemory-policy`, probably `allkeys-lru` in your case.

Comment: It looks like redis doesn't support what I need.  None of the eviction policies here match what I need: https://support.redislabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/203290657-What-eviction-policies-do-you-support-

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the eviction policies.  I didn't know this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The eviction policy determines what happens when a database reaches its memory limit. To make room for new data, older data is evicted (removed) according to the selected policy.

You can select the policies from the reference link below based on your requirement. The one I am using in the example below is "allkeys-lru"

[reference link](https://docs.redis.com/latest/rs/concepts/memory-performance/eviction-policy/)

Example -

```
127.0.0.1:6379> CONFIG SET maxmemory-policy allkeys-lru
    
OK
```

Example in Python -

```
import redis
client = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
client.config_set('maxmemory-policy', "allkeys-lru")
```

Comment: Sorry for slow upvote/answer.  Your solution mostly works; it's not exactly what I wanted, but in most cases it will work.